# 3 phase induction motor with one phase

Tags: three-phase, induction-motor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [2 Phase to 3 Phase conversion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/43058/2-phase-to-3-phase-conversion)

Is there a way to run a 3ph induction motor with one phase .

Basically I have 3ph motor but my power supply is only 2 phase . Is there anyway I can run it ?

Motor spec :

- 3ph
- induction motor
- Hi-tone
- ref to is 325
- FRAME 80  Duty S1  Hz 50    Insucl.cl.e
- V 400/440   RPM 1440  AMP 1.9
- K.W. 0.75   H.P 1  M.No : 11209

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this: http://www.nerdylorrin.net/jerry/ThreePhase.html. Looks like it's possible.

Comment: But that reduces the power of motor

Comment: Yeah that's true.  I don't see how you could operate at full efficiency off of just two phases.

Comment: I didn't see either so posted here :P